# Django API shows 400 (Bad Request) error using angular4

Tags: django, angular

I am using Django Rest API and calling it via Angular4 
but I get the error when I try to upload an image I get **bad request** error

**home.component.ts**
hear I am using post method for uploading an image with data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  homeObj:object = {};

  addSaveData = function(home){
    this.homeObj = {
      "name" : home.name,
      "email": home.email,
      "subject": home.subject,
      "message": home.message,
      "image" : home.image,
    }
    let _url:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/Homemodel/';
    this.http.post(_url, this.homeObj).subscribe(( res:Response) =>{
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is my **home.component.html**

it is angular4 code using as front-end for calling Django API.

```
<div id="headder" class="container"><h3>POST METHOD</h3></div>
<form  class="container" id="formNewPost" name="formNewPost" #postData = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "addSaveData(postData.value)">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div style="width:100%"><label>Name:</label></div>
    <input style="width:100%" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" ngModel>
   </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div style="width:100%"><label>EMail:</label></div>
    <input style="width:100%" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" ngModel>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div style="width:100%"></div><label>Subject:</label>
    <input style="width:100%" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="subject" ngModel>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div style="width:100%"><label>Message:</label></div>
    <textarea style="width:100%" type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message" ngModel></textarea>
  </div>
   <input type="file" >
</div><br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;margin-bottom:15px;" type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

Comment: can you try with post man?

Comment: yes i try, but get http 500 error

Comment: you have any link which guide how to post image and data from angular4 to Django??

Comment: i think your code is perfect but issue on server side

Comment: if this api not working in postman then it's not working on server or it's server error

Comment: and you got 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.

Comment: and 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: now working in post man

Comment: 500 is definitely server error while 400 means unexpected kind of datawas passed to the API. share your django code.

Comment: what error you getting after postman working?

Comment: in post man workin now but i still getting BED REQUEST error when i use angular4 as frunt-end